# Split values by hyphen that exist in the same row and integrate with a INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

A table in my database holds values as below,

```
               TBLFlow
FlowId         FlowName           ProcessId
------------------------------------------------
F00             Flow1         PID01-PID02-PID03

F01             Flow2         PID01-PID03-PID02
```

The Name of the process are listed in another table as below,

```
       TBLProcess
ProcessId     ProcessName
---------------------------
 PID01         Process1
 PID02         Process2
 PID03         Process3
```

Now, I would like to split the values in the table 'TBLFlow' in order to get their name from the table 'TBLProcess' by perform a join(preferably 'Inner Join') between two tables.
Finally, when I execute the query, I would like the result to be as below,

```
FlowId         FlowName         ProcessId               ProcessName
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 F01            Flow1        PID01-PID02-PID03     Process1-Process2-Process3 
 F01            Flow1        PID01-PID03-PID02     Process1-Process3-Process2
```

I am working on SQL Server 2008 and would like to do this operation in a single Stored Procedure.Could you help me on the query to written in the Stored Procedure.

**EDIT:**

Table 'TBLFlow' can be recontructed as below,

```
               TBLFlow
FlowId         FlowName           ProcessId
------------------------------------------------
F00             Flow1               PID01

F00             Flow1               PID02

F00             Flow1               PID03

F01             Flow2               PID01

F01             Flow2               PID03

F01             Flow2               PID02
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagined such a monster

```
DECLARE @TBLFlow table (FlowId varchar(20), FlowName varchar(100), ProcessId varchar(1000))
DECLARE @TBLProcess table (ProcessId varchar(20), ProcessName varchar(100))
insert into @TBLFlow values ('F00','Flow1','PID01-PID02-PID03'), ('F01','Flow2','PID01-PID03-PID02')
insert into @TBLProcess values ('PID01','Process1'), ('PID02','Process2'), ('PID03','Process3')

;with c as
(
    select 
        1 as rn,
        FlowId,
        FlowName,
        CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1) as Pos,
        case when CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1)>0 then SUBSTRING(ProcessId,1,CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1)-1) else ProcessId end as value,
        case when CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1)>0 then SUBSTRING(ProcessId,CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1)+1,LEN(ProcessId)-CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1)) else '' end as ProcessId
    from @TBLFlow

    union all
    select
        rn + 1 as rn,
        FlowId,
        FlowName,
        CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1) as Pos,
        case when CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1)>0 then SUBSTRING(ProcessId,1,CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1)-1) else ProcessId end as Value,
        case when CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1)>0 then SUBSTRING(ProcessId,CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1)+1,LEN(ProcessId)-CHARINDEX('-',ProcessId,1)) else '' end as ProcessId
    from c
    where LEN(ProcessId)>0
)
select
    f.FlowId,
    f.FlowName,
    f.ProcessId,
    stuff(
        (
            select '-'+p.ProcessName
            from c
            inner join @TBLProcess p on p.ProcessId=c.value
            where c.flowid=f.flowid
            order by c.rn
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),
        1,
        1,
        ''
    ) as ProcessName
from @TBLFlow f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT F.*,ISNULL(P1.ProcessName,'') + '-' + ISNULL(P2.ProcessName,'') + '-' +  
ISNULL(P3.ProcessName,'')
FROM TBLFlow AS F
LEFT JOIN TBLProcess AS P1
ON   SUBSTRING(F.ProcessId,0,CHARINDEX('-',F.ProcessId)) = P1.ProcessId
LEFT JOIN TBLProcess AS P2
ON LEFT(RIGHT(F.ProcessId,LEN(F.ProcessId)-CHARINDEX('-',F.ProcessId,1)),
CHARINDEX('-   ',RIGHT(F.ProcessId,LEN(F.ProcessId)-
CHARINDEX('-',F.ProcessId,1)),1)-1) 
= P2.ProcessId
LEFT JOIN TBLProcess AS P3
ON SUBSTRING(F.ProcessId, LEN(RIGHT(F.ProcessId,LEN(F.ProcessId)-
CHARINDEX('-',F.ProcessId))) + 2,LEN(F.ProcessId)) = P3.ProcessId
```

Comment: @Debajit..Which table did you work on. The first one or the edited?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are asking for two separate queries, one to solve your original table with the denormalized data in the `ProcessID` column and then a second query if the `tblFlow` data is normalized.

**tblFlow Denormalized query**

If you are not able to normalize the data in the `tblFlow` table, meaning you have data stored in the list separated with a dash (`PID01-PID02-PID03`). Then I would proceed the following way.

First, I would create a split string user defined function that will separate the `ProcessId` string, into multiple columns.  There are many functions online but this is the function that I typically use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end;
```

Once you have created the function. Then you would query using `CROSS APPLY` to pass in the `processId` list to the function. The query will be:

```
;with cte as
(
  select f.flowid, f.flowname, f.processid, s.items processItem
  from tblFlow f
  cross apply dbo.Split(f.processid, '-') s
) 
select *
from cte;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b2e7/2). This gives a result:

```
| FLOWID | FLOWNAME |         PROCESSID | PROCESSITEM |
-------------------------------------------------------
|    F00 |    Flow1 | PID01-PID02-PID03 |       PID01 |
|    F00 |    Flow1 | PID01-PID02-PID03 |       PID02 |
|    F00 |    Flow1 | PID01-PID02-PID03 |       PID03 |
|    F01 |    Flow2 | PID01-PID03-PID02 |       PID01 |
|    F01 |    Flow2 | PID01-PID03-PID02 |       PID03 |
|    F01 |    Flow2 | PID01-PID03-PID02 |       PID02 |
```

Once the `ProcessItem` data has been split into rows, then you are easily able to join to your existing table and generate a new concatenated list of `ProcessNames`. To create the concatenated list you can use `FOR XML PATH` and STUFF.  The query will be:

```
;with cte as
(
  select f.flowid, f.flowname, f.processid, s.items processItem
  from tblFlow f
  cross apply dbo.Split(f.processid, '-') s
) 
select distinct c.flowid,
  c.flowname,
  c.processid,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT '-' + p.ProcessName
          FROM cte c2
          inner join tblProcess p
            on c2.processItem = p.processId
          where c.flowid = c2.flowid
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS ProcessName
from cte c;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b2e7/4). This gives a result:

```
| FLOWID | FLOWNAME |         PROCESSID |                PROCESSNAME |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    F00 |    Flow1 | PID01-PID02-PID03 | Process1-Process2-Process3 |
|    F01 |    Flow2 | PID01-PID03-PID02 | Process1-Process2-Process3 |
```

**Normalized tblFlow**

Now if the `tblFlow` data is already normalized and you want to create two concatenated lists, one with `processId` and the other with `processName`, then you could use the following:

```
select distinct f.flowid,
  f.flowname,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT '-' + f1.Processid
          FROM tblFlow f1
          where f.flowid = f1.flowid
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Processid,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT '-' + p.ProcessName
          FROM tblFlow f1
          inner join tblProcess p
            on f1.ProcessId = p.ProcessId
          where f.flowid = f1.flowid
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS ProcessName
from tblFlow f;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85203/3). This creates a result:

```
| FLOWID | FLOWNAME |         PROCESSID |                PROCESSNAME |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|    F00 |    Flow1 | PID01-PID02-PID03 | Process1-Process2-Process3 |
|    F01 |    Flow2 | PID01-PID03-PID02 | Process1-Process2-Process3 |
```